# Is is possible to change frame_id of a sensor?

Tags: gazebo-edifice

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I would like to change frame_id of a laser sensor in ignition gazebo simulation plugin:

```
<plugin
  filename="libignition-gazebo-sensors-system.so"
  name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors">
```

But I couldn't find any support on how to do it: https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/gazebo/5.1/classignition_1_1gazebo_1_1systems_1_1Sensors.html

It seems like the frame_id for a sensor is always ${name_of_model}/${name_of_link}/${name_of_scan}.

It was possible to change odom frame_id and child_frame_id for the diff_drive plugin: https://ignitionrobotics.org/api/gazebo/5.1/classignition_1_1gazebo_1_1systems_1_1DiffDrive.html. So I would guess it might be possible also for sensors.

Any clue how to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27635/is-is-possible-to-change-frame_id-of-a-sensor?/) by [lucie.halodova](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/63749/lucie.halodova/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It doesn't look like you can change the frame_id for the internal ignition laser scan message but you can add the element below to the sdf under the sensor to get a custom frame_id when using the ros_ign bridge.

```
<ignition_frame_id>custom_name_here</ignition_frame_id>
```

---

Originally posted by [neap](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/81177/neap/) with karma: 16 on 2022-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on 2022-05-24**:
Thank you! Here is the related code parsing the frame_id string: https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sensors/blob/bbdb620d0ab9c3cc4331e8006f1ce1fa79f9bb2d/src/Sensor.cc#L148-L151